Flutter firebase upload symbols failed
env:
android :minSdk 21,targetSdk 34
java: 17
Flutter:3.22.0
build environment：Linux(centos 7)

Steps：

cd ProjectRootPath

flutter build appbundle --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=symbols

firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app=1:1459470:android:ad*9983d7 symbols
Result:
Crashlytics execution failed
enter code here
 java.io.IOException: Breakpad symbol generation failed (exit=1), see STDERR
         at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.breakpad.BreakpadSymbolGenerator.generateSymbols(BreakpadSymbolGenerator.java:129)
         at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.generateNativeSymbolFiles(Buildtools.java:306)
         at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.executeGenerateSymbols(CommandLineHelper.java:193)
         at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.executeCommand(CommandLineHelper.java:125)
         at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.CommandLineHelper.main(CommandLineHelper.java:72)
         at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.main(Buildtools.java:114)

 Error: java command failed with args: -jar,/root/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-3.0.2.jar,-symbolGenerator,breakpad,-symbolFileCacheDir,/tmp/crashlytics-7b06fa2b-4a3e-457b-8ec2-79791d623985/nativeSymbols/1-14592980470-android-add78aa91667d23c9983d7/breakpad,-verbose,-generateNativeSymbols,-unstrippedLibrary,symbols,-clientName,firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools



Symbols successfully reported to flutter

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
